# WPF: Combobox custom ContentTemplate display namespace.classname as selected item text

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I'm trying to style my combobox as below.

The dropdown is showing the correct list of names, but when selected the namespace.classname is shown as the combo text instead of the selected name.

I've got the following style and declaration of the combobox. Anyone has any idea what I've got wrong? Thanks!

```
<!--ComboBox Style-->
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="DefaultComboBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="26" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,4,25,4"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextHintingMode" Value="Animated"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TransparentLightestBrush}" />            
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>        
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="comboToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayBrush7}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder">
                                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBorder">
                                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedRectangle">
                                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedInnerRectangle">
                                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusRectangle">
                                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusInnerRectangle">
                                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Border x:Name="Background" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" Background="{StaticResource TransparentDarkBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3.5" Opacity="0"/>
                                            <Border x:Name="PressedBorder" Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush5}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3.5" Opacity="0"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusRectangle" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBoxMouseOverInnerBorderBrush}" RadiusY="4" RadiusX="4" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" />
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusInnerRectangle" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBoxMouseOverBorderBrush}" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Opacity="0" />
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="CheckedRectangle" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" RadiusY="4" RadiusX="4" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBoxMouseOverBorderBrush}" />
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="CheckedInnerRectangle" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" RadiusY="4" RadiusX="4" Opacity="0" Margin="1" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBoxMouseOverInnerBorderBrush}" />
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" RadiusY="3.5" RadiusX="3.5" Stroke="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0.45"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusRectangle">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusInnerRectangle">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                 ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                 ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                                 Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle"  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource comboToggleStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="4" Margin="0,0,6,0" Stretch="Uniform" Width="8">
                                    <Path.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BtnArrowColor" Color="{StaticResource Gray3}"/>
                                    </Path.Fill>
                                </Path>
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusRectangle" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBoxMouseOverInnerBorderBrush}" RadiusY="4" RadiusX="4" Margin="-1" Opacity="0" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusInnerRectangle" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{StaticResource TextBoxMouseOverBorderBrush}" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Opacity="0" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="{StaticResource DisabledWhiteColorBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="false" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Opacity="0"/>                        
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                           AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                        <Border Effect="{StaticResource DropShadowBrush}" x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBoxPopupBrush}" Background="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectionBoxHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" TargetName="PopupBorder" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

EDIT:

Thanks Ian.

This is the data I used. Just a simple operation of assigning the list to the combobox itemsource. When selecting any of the names, instead of displaying "Eric" or "Stan" or "Kyle", it's always showing "WpfCosmo.Person".

In my ControlsPage.xaml:

```
<ComboBox Height="22" Margin="0,0,0,5" x:Name="comboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedIndex="-1" />
```

In my code behind:

```
public partial class ControlsPage : Page
{
    public ControlsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox.ItemsSource = Person.GetList();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public static List<Person> GetList()
    {
        List<Person> SouthPark = new List<Person>() { 
            new Person() { Name = "Eric", Surname="Cartman" },
            new Person() { Name = "Stan", Surname="Marsh" },
            new Person() { Name = "Kyle", Surname="Broflovski" },
            new Person() { Name = "Kenny", Surname="McCormick" },
            new Person() { Name = "Bebe", Surname="Stevens" },
            new Person() { Name = "Clyde", Surname="Donovan" }, 
            new Person() { Name = "Craig", Surname="Tucker" }, 
            new Person() { Name = "Jimmy", Surname="Vulmer" }, 
            new Person() { Name = "Pip", Surname="Pirrup" }, 
            new Person() { Name = "Token", Surname="Black" }, 
            new Person() { Name = "Tweek", Surname="Tweak" }, 
            new Person() { Name = "Wendy", Surname="Testaburger" }, 
            new Person() { Name = "Annie", Surname="Polk" },
            new Person() { Name = "Randy", Surname="Marsh" },
            new Person() { Name = "Sharon", Surname="Marsh" },
            new Person() { Name = "Shelley", Surname="Marsh" },
            new Person() { Name = "Marvin", Surname="Marsh" },
            new Person() { Name = "Jimbo", Surname="Kern" },
            new Person() { Name = "Gerald", Surname="Broflovski" },
            new Person() { Name = "Sheila", Surname="Broflovski" },
            new Person() { Name = "Ike", Surname="Broflovski" },
            new Person() { Name = "Kyle", Surname="Schwartz" },
            new Person() { Name = "Liane", Surname="Cartman" },
            new Person() { Name = "Stuart", Surname="McCormick" },
            new Person() { Name = "Carol", Surname="McCormick" },
            new Person() { Name = "Kevin", Surname="McCormick" },
            new Person() { Name = "Stephen", Surname="Stotch" },
            new Person() { Name = "Linda", Surname="Stotch" },
            new Person() { Name = "Richard", Surname="Tweak" }
        };

        return SouthPark;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just pasted in your example, and I cannot reproduce the problem. I'm using a DataTemplate with its DataType set to my custom data type, and that template shows a property called 'Value' in a TextBlock. Your custom template here correctly applies that template in the combo text area. So I see the Value property in both places - not namespace.classname. So the problem must be specific to how you're using the ComboBox - we need more information.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also tried not using a DataTemplate - I just set DisplayMemberPath to refer to the Value property in my test. Again, it works fine with your template - I can't reproduce the problem you describe. Could you please provide a bit more information - how are you using the ComboBox? In particular, you say you want to see "the correct list of names" - what determines "correct" here? (WPF's default behaviour is to call ToString in some scenarios, so to see something other than namespace.classname, you'd need to tell WPF what you want. What have you told it?)

Comment: Any help? Prefer not to use datatemplate~ :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this part of the style:

```
Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old, but I had the same problem recently. I wanted a custom style for my comboboxes, so I started to extract the default template in Visual Studio to modify it. But when I did that, my comboboxes didn't work anymore.

After some researches on Google, I found a solution here : [StackOverFlow : Custom Template for ComboBox ignores use of DisplayMemberPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014370/custom-template-for-combobox-ignores-use-of-displaymemberpath)

The problem comes from the Visual Studio template extractor (I believe it's the same thing for Blend) which forget a property in the Content Presenter :

> ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"

This simple property has fixed the problem for me.

Hope this could help someone else.