# Custom Template for ComboBox ignores use of DisplayMemberPath

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, controltemplate

So I've gone through several questions on the site, and I cannot seem to find the answer.

I have a `ComboBox`. It was working just fine. I decide I need to overhaul the appearance, so I create a copy of the default ComboBox template (this is a straight copy, no modifications):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate2" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,0L3.5,4 7,0z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFAFAFAF"/>
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Now, when I select an item from my list (which is a collection of POCOs), it's display the namespace and class name instead of the value it's supposed to.

My research and experimentation have led me to believe that the problem is that my new template does not make use of the `DisplayMemberPath` property. I tried to set an `ItemTemplate` by overriding the `OnDisplayMemberPathChanged` method, but that results in errors when I select an item from the list.

I have also seen people set the `ItemTemplate` via XAML, but I have hundreds of comboboxes, and I don't want to do that.

Is there some way to utilize the `DisplayMemberPath` property in my ControlTemplate, or some code I could run in a derived control to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is *not* an exact copy, one crucial thing is missing in this element:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
        IsHitTestVisible="False"
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
```

Maybe you accidentally deleted it, namely:

```xml
 ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
```

If you do not have this set the `DisplayMemberPath` will not work because the `ComboBox` selects between templates using a template selector (as you can use `ItemTemplate` or `DisplayMemberPath`).

Comment: Dude! That totally worked. I never saw that solution though, and I'm 100% positive it was never generated. I have done this process 3 or 4 times, and checked scores of people with the same problem. This must totally be a bug on Microsoft's side... Thank you!

Comment: Now that the joy has subsided, I must ask how you figured that out. What are you using to generate template copies?

Comment: @CamronBute: Well, i always have the default templates that you can get [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) (`Default WPF Themes` link) at hand, so i checked it out to see how things are bound up. It isn't hard to see that this `ContentPresenter` is the key component for the selected item so if there is an error it should be there, then i just needed to compare it with yours to see that this property was missing. I also tested the effect of removing that property myself and as expected it only showed the type name.

Comment: I have never seen that link before. I have always used Blend. Thank you for your help, and the link!

Comment: I can confirm that the blend "copy template" has this quirk, even in VS2012.

Comment: Same thing happend with VS 2015

Comment: In my situation I had the combo box template correct but the ItemsContainerStyle was missing the ContentTemplateSelector. Make sure to check out the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are not missing the ContentTemplateSelector elements.

For the combox template itself it should be:

```
ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
```

For the ItemsContainerStyle it should be:

```
ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486905/302677), and it turns out setting the `DisplayMemberPath` is simply a shortcut way for setting the `ItemTemplate` to a `TextBlock` with that value in it.

Because of this, when you set the `ItemTemplate` then `DisplayMemberPath` becomes useless because you have overwritten the default TextBlock with value that it adds.

Comment: Check the answer above. I saw your problem in a related question, but the above solution works for me! Thanks anyway, though :)

Comment: I used the solution by H.B. but consequent to this answer, trying `ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"` also worked - though I didn't bother leaving it long enough to test for any side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, this should be a bug, I'll try report it.

When you "edit a copy" of the control template from Visual Studio, it misses the line:

ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"

Which caused "DisplayMemberPath" not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I faced the same problem in these days and I fixed it adding 
`ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"`
instead of 
`ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"`